# vue multiselect filter(get select$)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-multiselect

This is component and API
https://github.com/vueform/multiselect

| Event | Attributes | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| @search-change | query, select$ | Emitted after a character is typed. |

i need to get select$.filteredOptions

```
  methods: {
    inputQuery(query, select$){
      console.log(query, select$);
    },
```

in console:
"query"- this is symbols, which i inputed
"select$" - undefined, but it should be "proxy" this select

Perhaps this trouble arose due to the fact that Multiselect was raised through an intermediary component.

```
<SelectComponent v-model="countryId" :options="countries" />
```

#SelectComponent.vue

```
<Multiselect
      :options="options"
      @search-change="inputQuery"
```

Props are passed here and events too so that it works for all the select in app
Can someone tell me what can be done to see "select$" ?

Emmiting events don't help me

```
<SelectComponent  @searchChange="inputQuery2" />

 methods: {
    inputQuery2(query,select$){
      console.log(query,select$);
    },
```

#SelectComponent.vue

```
<Multiselect
    @search-change="inputQuery"

emits: ['search-change'],   
methods: {  
    inputQuery(query,select$){
      this.$emit('search-change', query, select$);
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are working with an async promise variant of the Multiselect component entry.

You can try changing your method setup to support the async operation:
(also note that you were missing a spacebar after 'query,')

```
methods: {
async inputQuery(query, select$) {
```

Comment: not work with async too =(

Comment: You can try the following in combination with my previous answer, I believe the syntax for the emitted event should be:

<SelectComponent  @search-change="inputQuery2" />

Comment: with search-change not work at all